# ASP.Net Core 7 Entity Relationships and Viewing Data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 and I have models `Project` and `DataListItem`.

I need to create a relationship between the two so that I can display the value in the view of the `DataListItem` (`DataListValue`).

The `Project` class may have multiple references to the `DataListItem` model.

```
public class Project
{
    ProjectId
    [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
    [Required]

    [ForeignKey("DataListItem")]
    public int Project_Status { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a model called `DataListItem`

```
public class DataListItem
{
    [Key] 
    public int DataListId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public string DataListValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Display(Name = "Default")]
 }
```

I want to create a relationship between the two such that in my view I can add something like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => project.Project_Status.DataListValue)
```

Have tried multiple ways and I am struggling.

Comment: As a side note, I have tried a number of combinations resulting in issue with Linq queries and then with For/Loop SQL exceptions during run time. Clearly I'm missing something simple here. This is what i tried..

        [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
        [Required]
        public int Project_StatusId { get; set; } // Foreign key property

       [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
        public DataListItem Project_StatusVal { get; set; } // Navigation property

        [ForeignKey("Project_Status")]
        public virtual DataListItem ProjectStatus { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, you seems to wanna create a relationship between `Project` and `DataListItem`, Then in the view show the property in `DataListItem` which correspond to the current `Project`. Because I don't know what kind of relationship you want to create, So here i create a `one-to-many` relationship as example.

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
        [Required]
        public int Project_StatusId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Status")]
        [ForeignKey("Project_StatusId")]
        public DataListItem Project_Status { get; set; }

        public string propertyA { get; set; }
    }

public class DataListItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int DataListId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Value")]
        public string DataListValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the table construct in database will be like:

[image]

[image]

If I want to show `DataListValue` in current view, I can use:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var value = _context.projects.Where(x => x.ProjectId == 1).Include(x => x.Project_Status).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(value);
        }
```

View

```
@model Project

@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Project_Status.DataListValue)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.propertyA)
```

[image]

Hope this demo can help you solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response :-) 
There is a Single Project which has a one value of DataListItem stored. The DataListItems store the possible values for the project status. I've implemented your suggested changes, however on the form when I have the dropdown list, the Controller fails to validate the data returned and both Project_Status and Project_StatusId are noll/0. I am binding both the Project_Status and Project_StatusId in the controller.

Comment: <input class="form-control" hidden="" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Project_StatusId field is required." id="Project_StatusId" name="Project_StatusId" value="0"><input name="__Invariant" type="hidden" value="Project_StatusId">
    <select class="form-control" id="Project_StatusId" name="Project_StatusId">
        <option value="78">Pre-Sales</option>
        <option value="79">Open</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Project_Status" data-valmsg-replace="true">The Project Status field is required.</span>

Comment: Hi @Laurence Thomas, So the relationship between `Project` and `DataListItem` is one-to-one? And you want to create a dropdown list to select the value of `DataListItem` in `Project`?

Comment: Have sorted it, A project could have many status values, but only selects one. My misunderstanding here was that the Models would allow some more functionality when developing the screens. Once I realised that was not the case (per-se), I was quickly able to use your code to help sort stuff out and everything now works! Thanks so much !!